# How should I edit my question to explain how it's not a duplicate?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17321341/can-we-use-the-jquery-on-for-the-statically-created-dom-element-and-what-is-th) has been marked as a duplicate by five users:

> This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please edit this question to explain how it is different or ask a new question.

I want to explain how my question is not a duplicate. How can I do this? Should I leave comments explaining the differences? What else should I do?

Comment: "please **edit this question** to explain how it is different" - use the edit link below your question to edit it.

Comment: I have already edited the question before I seen that link, how to explain that?

Comment: Well the you're good. You already have 4 re-open votes, be patient.

Comment: @Thirumalai You don't seem to have added anything that states how your question is different from the duplicate. You just moved a paragraph from the middle to the top.

Comment: @Asad Yes I didnt added any think because I dont know where to nominate that thats why I came here to ask

Comment: @Thirumalai Sorry if I'm being a bit slow (2 AM here): what are you looking to nominate?

Comment: @Mat one person nominate to close my question and commented(Zenith) on my question for that I replied him how its similar and I shown my differences to him then he become dumb and removed his comment not his nominate to close the question

Comment: @Asad first of all I thank you for your support it is not late reply from you.... I want to show "for the statically created DOM element (I know that will work but I want to know is it good to use?)" is it there how its exactly duplicate

Comment: @Thirumalai: it's not possible to retract a close vote. The message already tells you what to do: edit your question to explain why it's not a duplicate. Comments are ok, but it's better if you edit the question. That puts your question in the reopen queue that other users will see and vote to reopen as they see fit.

Comment: thank you people that question get reopened thanks guys and please provide answer for my question since it will be help full to other users too

Answer (score 3):

In this case, simply rearranging your question and bringing it up on Meta seems to have been sufficient. In the general case however, it is a safer bet to explicitly highlight what it is your question is asking that the marked duplicate is not.

I personally think the main question *was* answered under the linked duplicate (quite well in fact). Regarding your follow-on question:

> I want to know is it good to use

This isn't a very good question as it stands, because the only correct answer is "it depends". If you had a specific use case where you could not make do without event delegation, you'd have to use `on`. If you were just binding to an element that is already present, the two approaches are functionally identical (although `on` lets you dynamically pick the event type and specify multiple event types simultaneously).

Comment: thank you asad but second question also worth I feel so, because I came to know click() also internally call the on('click') by their answer +1 for your marvelous support